# Loading of uniform structures to the fragment glsl shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

There is the fragment shader with structures inside. Here is a part of the code:

```
#version 330          

const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 3;

in vec2 texCoord0;
in vec3 normal0;
in vec3 worldPos0;

out vec4 fragColor;

struct BaseLight
{
  vec3  color;
  float ambientIntensity;
  float diffuseIntensity;
};

struct DirectionalLight
{
  BaseLight base;
  vec3 direction;
};

struct Attenuation
{
  float constant;
  float linear;
  float expVar;
};

struct PointLight
{
  BaseLight     base;
  vec3          position;
  Attenuation   atten;
};

uniform int                 gNumPointLights;
uniform PointLight          gPointLights [ MAX_POINT_LIGHTS ];
uniform DirectionalLight    gDirectionalLight;
//...
```

In my application i need to transfer some data to the uniform paramets of shader. Compilation of shader was succeessful, pipeline is correct. Before tranferring data we need uniform positions. Here is what i did:

```
  //...
  m_WVPLocation         = GetUniformLocation ( "gWVP" );
  m_WorldMatrixLocation = GetUniformLocation ( "gWorld" );
  m_samplerLocation     = GetUniformLocation ( "gSampler" );


  m_dirLightLocation.color            =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.base.color" );
  m_dirLightLocation.ambientIntensity =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.base.ambientIntensity" );
  m_dirLightLocation.diffuseIntensity =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.base.diffuseIntensity" );
  m_dirLightLocation.direction        =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.direction" );

  m_eyeWorldPosLocation           = GetUniformLocation ( "gEyeWorldPos" );
  m_matSpecularIntensityLocation  = GetUniformLocation ( "gMatSpecularIntensity" );
  m_matSpecularPowerLocation      = GetUniformLocation ( "gSpecularPower" );
  //...
```

Because of nesting of the structures i cannot get positions of the fields with nesting level 2 or more, except the first field. For example, for `gDirectionalLight` i got position of this fields:

- `gDirectionalLight.base.color`
- `gDirectionalLight.direction`

And didn't get for this:

- `gDirectionalLight.base.ambientIntensity`
- `gDirectionalLight.base.diffuseIntensity`

I cannot believe that the only solution is repetition of code in the shader. Clarification: cannot get positions of only `ase.ambientIntensity` and `base.diffuseIntensity` fields in any structure. In the GLSL 3.0 nesting of structures are supported for non-anonymous structures due to the specifications. OpenGL version is 3.x

Comment: It is [bad] transaltion from the russian language. Something can be written bad, so ask me please.

Comment: Can you confirm the OpenGL version being used (in the context creation) ?

Comment: Nested structures should not pose a problem. Are you sure that the `gDirectionalLight.base.ambientIntensity` uniforms are actually _active_? You should post the full shader codes.